# Migrating analytics.js to Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We currently use analytics.js for cross domain tracking. I need to migrate our Universal Google Analytics tracking to go through Google Tag Manager.

I set up the Universal Google Analytics tag and then in more settings added "Fields to Set" field name=allowLinker value=true. Also, in Cross Domain Tracking, I added our two other domains in the Auto Link Domains field.

I am wondering what else I need to configure to ensure a smooth transition to capture accurate data. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you edit your question to include your hostnames people will give you personalised feedback. The only additional thing to remember would be to add referral exclusions to GA under Admin > Property > Tracking Info > Referral Exclusion List.

Comment: And there would be three properties created in GA for each domain right? So would I need to add referral exclusions to each of the properties? real.vision is the main site, build.real.vision is a second domain, and then the third is toursler.com, which was the old website before we rebranded to real.vision. We are holding off on redirecting toursler to real.vision for the time being. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Hi, are you using Universal Analytics and having all traffic feed into one GA property or so you still have each hostname having their own GA property? Why would this be the case: "And there would be three properties created in GA for each domain right?"